# sentry upload failure message in Android release APK(signed)?

Tags: android, react-native, sentry, react-native-sentry

Working on the react-native app with go-Lang, In the sentry plugin facing issue while generating the release APK file. But we can able generate debug APK through android studio.

Android studio error messages:
sentry reported an error: You do not have permission to perform this action. (http status: 403)
Process 'command 'node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUploadCleanUp SKIPPED
Skipping task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUploadCleanUp' as task onlyIf is false.
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUploadCleanUp (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 8,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets_SentryUpload'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

I tried blow steps are tired

1. Followed https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/react-native/advanced-setup/
2. I removed the line cli.executable=node_modules/@sentry/cli/bin/sentry-cli in android/sentry.properties
3. Modified logLevel: "debug/release"
4. Verified with enableHermes true/false

Which is source stoping us, any guidelines will help to proceed further.

Comment: Sounds like you don't have an auth token to call Sentry's API (at development time) in order to upload you sourcemaps.

Comment: @BrunoGarcia : Generated the auth token in sentry console. which is account specific one. Is possible to create project specific?. So I try to run multiple apps with same auth token getting error : error: API request failed
  caused by: [56] Failure when receiving data from the peer

Add --log-level=[info|debug] or export SENTRY_LOG_LEVEL=[info|debug] to see more output.
Please attach the full debug log to all bug reports.
API request failed

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware to the name of the project in your sentry.io site.
I changed my project name from "react-native" to "my-project", and i got this error.

so I went to this path:
android/sentry.properties
and i changed the line 3

```
defaults.project=react-native
```

to this:

```
defaults.project=my-project
```

and the error is gone!

I am sure it will help.